# JavaFX component only not showing when running the application

Tags: java, javafx, invisible

i have a small application with javafx in it. i created the fxml-files with the scene builder. i am loading them with a fxmlloader. so far so good, but if i start the application, only one component is not shown. the rest of the gui works fine. first i thought i didn't add it, but scene builder shows it to me when i open a preview and i also found it in the fxml-structure. after trying a few things out, i started the application on another computer and the component was showing. it is only not showing on my computer. Both machines are working with the same jdk (java 8), so how is this possible?

Here my fxml-structure. The component which isn't showing is the menu "Aktion" of the menu-bar. the menu-bar is visible. Only the item is missing for some stupid reason

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="410.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.gigatronik.azubi.kontaktverwaltung.gui.controller.DetailController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="410.0">   
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Aktion">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onEdit" text="Bearbeiten" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteContact" text="Löschen" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
    </menus>
  </MenuBar>
  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="50.0" text="Vorname:" />
  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="90.0" text="Nachname:" />
  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="130.0" text="E-Mail:" />
  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="170.0" text="Telefon:" />
  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="210.0" text="Rolle:" />
  <Label fx:id="firstNameLabel" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="50.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="305.0" text="*firstName*" />
  <Label fx:id="surnameLabel" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="90.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="305.0" text="*surName*" />
  <Label fx:id="eMailLabel" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="130.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="305.0" text="*email*" />
  <Label fx:id="phoneNumberLabel" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="170.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="305.0" text="*phoneNumber*" />
  <Label fx:id="roleLabel" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="210.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="305.0" text="*roleDescription*" />
  <TitledPane fx:id="organisationTPane" expanded="false" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="250.0" prefWidth="390.0" text="Organisation">
    <content>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="140.0" prefWidth="200.0">
           <children>
              <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="20.0" text="Name:" />
              <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="60.0" text="Straße/Hnr.:" />
              <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="100.0" text="PLZ/Stadt:" />
              <Label fx:id="orgaNameLabel" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="20.0" text="*name*" />
              <Label fx:id="orgaStreetHnrLabel" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="60.0" text="*street/hrn*" />
              <Label fx:id="orgaZipCodeCityLabel" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="100.0" text="*zipCode/city*" />
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </content>
  </TitledPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Thanks for help

Baschdi

Comment: Hm, Aktion Menu is visible for me, but i removed `fx:controller="com.gigatronik.azubi.kontaktverwaltung.gui.controller.DetailController"` and `onAction` from MenuItems, so probably you are doing something in your controller to hide menu?

Comment: No im not doing anything in my controller. That's the weird thing. It is showing up on other computers perfectly. Only on mine the exact same code does something differen xD i don't get it

Comment: Did you manage to make this work? I've a similar problem when my elements show in preview but not when I run the application.